# Upgraded after loss many file

Tags: css, upgrade, magento2.2, file

**PHP7.1**

**Magento `2.2.0`** upgraded to **`2.2.1`**

After my **vendor** , **pub/static/*** and **theme** loss many file and no **`css`**

How can I do?

Please help thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: can't , updated in original post, please see

Comment: Run `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

Comment: updated in original post, please see~thank you

Comment: updated in original post again ,please check ^^"" now is production

Comment: Try to remove the /generated first.

Comment: Also run `chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/`

Comment: updated in original post again ,please check

Comment: Have you removed the generated folder?

Comment: yes , removed  .....

Comment: Try to run again the command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`  and post the error log.

Comment: Updated in original post . And error log have not update, do you know why?

Comment: Check the system.log file

Comment: Updated system.log file  in original post

Comment: Try to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and see the log

Comment: updated in original post again ,please check and what log?

Comment: which version of php you are using?

Comment: PHP Version 7.1.12 ^^"

Comment: Try to add this command `opcache_reset();` in the header of your index.php inside the root folder.

Comment: An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. <--show this now, checking var/log/exception log?thank you!

Comment: check in var/log/exception.log

Comment: updated in original post, please see~thank you

Comment: Seems like it is a bug of php7.1.12. I'm not sure!

Comment: the bug about this? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html and https://www.tecmint.com/install-varnish-cache-web-accelerator/ ? beacuse i installed this in my server

Comment: does it matter?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know exactly what it is.

Comment: do you have skype?we can text on skype